# Struts2, type conversion and json plugin (struts2-json-plugin-2.3.14.2)

Tags: struts2, localization, struts2-json-plugin

I have created a web application that simulates an excel spreadsheet.

I would like to use Spanish number format. Example 2.345,67 and not american format: 2,345.67
In the server side I save these values in a List of BigDecimal numbers (`List<BigDecimal>`). 
To send the information from client to server and server to client I am using Ajax with Json.

The problem is that automatically only works the american format (1,234.56). I suppose that I need to create a Type Conversion but It seems that when I am using in the server the package json-default it doesn't work.

Please help.

Comment: Type conversion perfectly works with real numbers, all you need is to switch to a locale.

Comment: I will check the updates on this.